# What...? Goodness... I must be slipping

Tags: riddle

> I come with time
> To most, if not all people
> Don't forget, you might get me too
> I am a very emotional pendulum
> And can cause people to go mad
> Remember, I'm not uncommon
> Tens of millions is my count
> I take what is precious from you
> Yet you won't know when I do

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be

> Memory Loss

I come with time

> Stereotypically, older folks tend to get memory loss

To most, if not all people

> Probably in some form or another

Don't forget, you might get me too

> Play on words - How are we going to remember if we can't?

I am a very emotional pendulum

> Memory loss can be very traumatic to a person or their family

And can cause people to go mad

> Play on words? - They lost their mind

Remember, I'm not uncommon
Tens of millions is my count

> Millions are affected by at least a type of memory loss - Alzheimer's

I take what is precious from you

> Precious memories

Yet you won't know when I do

> I forgot I lost that memory

Title

> "I forgot" could be said like "It slipped my mind"

Answer (score 1):

As a tentative guess, are you...

> old age, by any chance?

> I come with time
> To most, if not all people

> As time passes, people get older; however, some people do die young and don't reach old age.

> Don't forget, you might get me too

> I mean... hopefully.

> I am a very emotional pendulum

> This line I'm still unsure of.

> And can cause people to go mad

> As people get older, some start to lose some of their mental faculties.

> Remember, I'm not uncommon
> Tens of millions is my count

> Lots and lots of people have gotten old. :)

> I take what is precious from you
> Yet you won't know when I do

> ...your life, I guess? And you won't know, because, well, you'll be dead of old age. Whee.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I come with time
> 2. To most, if not all people
> 3. Don't forget, you might get me too
> 4. I am a very emotional pendulum
> 5. And can cause people to go mad
> 6. Remember, I'm not uncommon
> 7. Tens of millions is my count
> 8. I take what is precious from you
> 9. Yet you won't know when I do

> Maybe the answer is white-hair: It comes with time (1) to most, if not all people (2) given that the person lives enough. Nobody is free from it (3), unless dying really young, so it's very common (6), it's much more than tens of millions if you multiply by the population (7). Some people freak-out when they notice it (5) - some get very emotional about it (4) and also the hair can swing like a pendulum (4). 
>  
>  It leaves only (8) and (9) unanswered... 
>  
>  Maybe: It takes your life away (8) and it's so slow that you can't notice (9).